# How can I resolve the react-hydration-error caused by the use of client side rendering in React with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

conjunction with the useEffect hook in React. My objective is to incorporate client-side rendering while ensuring the prevention of react-hydration-errors.

As I understand, client-side rendering entails rendering components on the client's browser instead of the server, leading to improved performance and interactivity. However, during the transition to client-side rendering, issues may arise due to inconsistencies between the initial server-side rendered HTML and the subsequent client-side rendered components, resulting in react-hydration-errors.

Considering this context, I would greatly appreciate your guidance on effectively utilizing the useEffect hook to achieve proper client-side rendering without encountering any react-hydration-errors. I am seeking a professional approach to address this challenge and would be grateful for any best practices, strategies, or code examples that you can share.

Thank you in advance for your invaluable assistance.

This is my sample code:

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

```
"use client"
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AiOutlineClose, AiOutlineMenu } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { motion, useScroll } from 'framer-motion';
import logo from '../public/logo_navbar_adobe_express.svg';
import { variants } from '../utils/motion';
import { BsArrowRightCircle } from 'react-icons/bs'
import styles from '../styles';

function useWindowSize(nav, setNav) {
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState([0, 0]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function updateWindowSize() {
      setWindowSize([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]);
      if (window.innerWidth >= 768 && nav) {
        setNav(false);
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', updateWindowSize);
    updateWindowSize();

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateWindowSize);
  }, [nav, setNav]);

  return windowSize;
}

const Navbar = () => {
  const [nav, setNav] = useState(false);
  const windowSize = useWindowSize(nav, setNav);
  const isMobile = windowSize[0] < 768;
  const handleNav = () => {
    setNav(!nav);
  };

  /** this hook gets the scroll y-axis **/
  const { scrollY } = useScroll();
  /** this hook manages state **/
  const [hidden, setHidden] = React.useState(false);

  /** this onUpdate function will be called in the `scrollY.onChange` callback **/
  function update() {
    if (scrollY?.current < scrollY?.prev) {
      setHidden(false);
    } else if (scrollY?.current > 100 && scrollY?.current > scrollY?.prev) {
      setHidden(true);
    }
  }

  /** update the onChange callback to call for `update()` **/
  useEffect(() => {
    return scrollY.onChange(() => update());
  }, [scrollY]); // Add scrollY as a dependency


  return (
    <motion.nav
    
      variants={variants}
      initial="hidden"
      animate={hidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible'}
      /** I'm also going to add a custom easing curve and duration for the animation **/
      transition={{ ease: [0.1, 0.25, 0.3, 1], duration: 0.6 }}
      className={`navbar-bg dark:bg-gray-900 fixed w-full z-20 top-0 left-0`}
    >
      <div className="absolute w-[20%] inset-0 gradient-01" />
      <div className="max-w-screen-xl flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto p-4">
        <Link href="/">
          <Image
            src={logo}
            alt="/"
            className="cursor-pointer"
            width="175"
            height="175"
          />
        </Link>
```

the useWindowSize function seems to be triggering the react-hydration-error

Answer (score 0):

Apparently to fix this issue, I just run `npm install next@latest`